# IIS6: Cannot connect to websites suddenly

Tags: iis-6

We got a **IIS6**, residing on VMWare. Yesterday, we **failed to connect a website** on that.

What kind of troubleshooting steps can we do, such as log files?

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably going to have to be a bit more specific than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have other sites on that installation? If so, do they work?

Are all of the related IIS services started (HTTP SSL, WWWPublishing, IIS Admin)?

Does the website still exist on the server? The directory hasn't been moved/deleted?

Have you looked through your event viewer logs and your IIS logs? What did you find?